# Issue implementing InceptionV3 with binary classifier - transfer learning with Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, transfer-learning, torchvision

I'm having an issue getting Inception V3 to work as the feature extractor with a binary classifier in Pytorch. I update the primary and auxiliary nets in Inception to have the binary class (as done in https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html)

but I'm getting an error

```
#Parameters for Inception V3
num_classes= 2 
model_ft = models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)
# set_parameter_requires_grad(model_ft, feature_extract)
#handle auxilliary net 
num_ftrs = model_ft.AuxLogits.fc.in_features
model_ft.AuxLogits.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
#handle primary net
num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs,num_classes)
# input_size = 299

#simulate data input 
x = torch.rand([64, 3, 299, 299])

#create model with inception backbone
backbone = model_ft
num_filters = backbone.fc.in_features
layers = list(backbone.children())[:-1]
feature_extractor = nn.Sequential(*layers)

# use the pretrained model to classify damage 2 classes
num_target_classes = 2
classifier = nn.Linear(num_filters, num_target_classes)

feature_extractor.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    representations = feature_extractor(x).flatten(1)
x = classifier(representations)
```

But Im getting the error

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-c2be64b8a99e> in <module>()
     11 feature_extractor.eval()
     12 with torch.no_grad():
---> 13     representations = feature_extractor(x)
     14 x = classifier(representations)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    442                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    443         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 444                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    445 
    446     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Expected 3D (unbatched) or 4D (batched) input to conv2d, but got input of size: [64, 2]
```

before I updated the class to 2 (when it was 1000) I was getting the same error but with   [64, 1000]. This method of creating a backbone and adding a classifier worked for Resnet but not here. I think it's because of the auxiliary net structure but not sure how to update it to deal with the dual output? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting `feature_extracture` by `children` function at line `layers = list(backbone.children())[:-1]` will bring the module from `backbone` to `feature_extracture` only, not the operation in `forward` function.

Let's take a look at the code below:

```py
class Example(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.avg = torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1,1))
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.avg(x)
        out = out.squeeze()
        out = self.linear(out)
        return out

x = torch.randn(5, 10, 12, 12)

model = Example()
y = model(x) # work well

new_model = torch.nn.Sequential(*list(model.children()))
y = new_model(x) # error
```

Module `model`  and `new_model` have the same blocks but not the same way of working. In `new_module`, the output from the pooling layer is not squeezed yet, so the shape of linear input is violate its assumption which causes the error.

In your case, the last two comments are redundant and that's why it returns the error, you did create a new `fc` in the InceptionV3 module at line `model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs,num_classes)`. Therefore, replace the last one as the code below should work fine:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    x = model_ft(x)
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense - in the Resnet I hadnt manually updated the classifier layers like I did here. Does having the torch no_grad mean that this wont train any of the model? Ideally I want to be training the classifier layer

Comment: you're correct, wrapping the code by `torch_no_grad` will help the inference faster because no gradient is computed so no backpropagation. If you want to train the classifier only, please take a look [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-the-pytorch-freeze-network-in-some-layers-only-the-rest-of-the-training/7088)